# gigabit mini pcie wifi card with AP mode

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, pcie, wpa

I set up a DIY router years back using a fitlet i "barebones" mini PC with a mini PCIe **intel 7260** wifi card (using the iwlwifi driver) running in AP mode (bridged to the ethernet coming in from my cable modem). lots of hacks to get it to function including WPA supplicant, hostapd, etc.

unfortunately, even after lots of trial and error to get this card to work, I could never get it to function above 54mbps even though it says it's a 5ghz "dual band" card (seems 5ghz AC is only supported in client mode, and it only has one radio). this worked fine for slow 100mbps cable internet.

but I recently discovered I now have symmetric gigabit internet offered in my neighborhood and signed up.

**what are my options for faster mini PCIe wifi AP adapter supported on ubuntu? is there such a thing?** even 100mbps would be nice, but gigabit wifi would be awesome. alternatively, if there's a way to force the faster speed for AP mode on my current card, I'd be thrilled.

hostapd conf below (copied from https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2014-intel-7260-access-point)

```
auth_algs=1
beacon_int=50

#channel=36 #for N/5ghz
channel=11

#disassoc_low_ack=1
driver=nl80211

# Operation mode (a = IEEE 802.11a (5 GHz), b = IEEE 802.11b (2.4 GHz), G = G
# hw_mode=a
hw_mode=g

# wme_enabled=1

# wifi N
#ieee80211n=1

ht_capab=[HT40-][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][DSSS_CCK-40][DSSS_CCK-40][DSSS_CCK-40]

#ieee80211d=1   # allow country freq only
country_code=US # country code
#ieee80211ac=1  # 802.11ac support - this shows up as not an option?
#vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42 - also not supported?

interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
require_ht=1

ssid=magi
wmm_enabled=1   # QoS support
wpa=2           # WPAv2 only
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=password
```

output of iw reg get

```
country US:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40)
```

output of iw list

```
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x11e2
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x11e2
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (17.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (17.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (17.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (17.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 20
    max scan IEs length: 425 bytes
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * Unknown mode (10)
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ Unknown mode (10) } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * action
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * Unknown command (75)
         * Unknown command (84)
         * Unknown command (87)
         * Unknown command (85)
         * Unknown command (89)
         * Unknown command (92)
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
         * wake up on 4-way handshake
         * wake up on rfkill release
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
```

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried hw_mode=a? "For IEEE 802.11ac (VHT), this # needs to be set to hw_mode=a." See: /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf

Comment: yes. setting hw mode to "a" (802.11a / 5ghz) results in the AP not working. not sure if this is a bug or a feature. basically it's what I'm posting about.

note that both bands report 54mbps as the top speed regardless of which band or 802.11 standard is used.

my question is really if anyone knows of a mini pcie card that supports AP mode at high-speed... I know the hardware exists because there are hundreds of consumer-grade APs with this feature set.